# Not able to access photos, songs from phone storage

Tags: internal-storage, media-files

I am not able to access data on my phone storage through mobile apps. However, I am able to access the same data from my PC using s USB connection.

I already erased all data available on the phone, restarted the phone, and took some photos but the Gallery app still says "no photos/videos available". How can I fix this issue?